# how to add grid column values dynamically using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have to add value  one of the grid column dynamically. Actually it's adding but its adding as a another row. but it's need to add in same row.

Here the simple grid example code and link http://jsfiddle.net/bagya1985/xojke83s/3/

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    "dataSource": {
                      "schema": {
                        "model": {
                          "id": "id",   
                          "fields": {       
                            "OperationContext": {
                              "type": "string",                              
                              "editable": "false"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }                     
                    },
                    "editable": "popup",
                    "toolbar": [
                      {
                        "name": "create",
                        "text": "Add a New Record"
                      }
                    ],
                    "columns": [
                      {

                        "field": "Name",
                        "title": "Name"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "Age",
                        "title": "Age"

                      },
                      {
                        "field": "OperationContext",
                        "title": "Operation Context"
                      },
                      { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }
                         ]
                        });

          $(".k-grid-add").on("click", function () {

              var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data([{OperationContext: "IsAdded"}]);
                 console.log(grid);            
           });
```

Please help anyone to achieve this.

Comment: "when ever Add Record event firing that time i have to add default column value "IsAdded" likewise edit and delete."

It isn't clear what you try to achieve, here. You may want to spend a bit more time to write down what you really meant.

Comment: @StefanoMagistri  can you check now please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just saw your fiddle makes me understand what do you want to achieve, if you want to add like default value (dynamically) for your model whenever you click add button you can try to do experiment with Grid's `edit` event. You can access current row object from it and modify its value using `set` method.

Try this code, taken and modified from your fiddle

```
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      schema: {
        model: {
          id: "id",
          fields: {
            OperationContext: {
              type: "string",
              editable: "false"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    editable: "popup",
    toolbar: [{
      name: "create",
      text: "Add a New Record"
    }],
    columns: [{
      field: "Name",
      title: "Name"
    }, {
      field: "Age",
      title: "Age"
    }, {
      field: "OperationContext",
      title: "Operation Context"
    }, {
      command: ["edit", "destroy"],
      title: "&nbsp;",
      width: "250px"
    }],
    edit: function (e) {
      var model = e.model;

      if (model.isNew()) { // add new record
        model.set("OperationContext", "IsAdded");
      }
    }
  });
```

[Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/aveGi/3)

Here read some their [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid) for futher development.

**UPDATE**

If you want to update that property after record is saved, change `edit` event to `save` event, and `model.isNew()` will help you determine is model newly added or taken from database(remote service).

For delete operation its need a little bit tweak with `remove` event. You should prevent it to remove the data from data source and then take advantage of data source filter to only display data which have `OperationContext` not equal with `IsDeleted`.

See updated [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/aveGi/2) and I encourage you to read their [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid) about Grid, people here usually don't do your homework

**UPDATE**

> Please help me without id property or how to add id property
>   dynamically for all rows

new datasource model schema

```
dataSource: {
  schema: {
    model: {
      id: "id",
      fields: {
        OperationContext: { type: "string", editable: "false" },
        Local: { type: "bool", editable: "false", defaultValue: true }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then your edit function

```
edit: function (e) {
  var model = e.model;

  if (model.Local) {
    model.set("OperationContext", "IsAdded");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. another one thing i have to do while clicking edit button i have to add Operation context value " IsUpdate" and for delete button "IsDelete". I tried inside of edit event which one you suggested. it's not working.How can i achieve? pleae help me.

Comment: So this value will be added after CRUD operation? You can see on datasource transport [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport) and use events create, update and destroy..

Comment: CRUD Operation(ADD,EDIT,DELETE)
These three values we have to send with grid dataSource based on the Events.   'IsAdded' - This must be add while adding new record to the Grid. After adding if user editing that record that time also it should be same as 'IsAdded' not 'IsUpdate'.
'IsUpdate' - This must be add at the time of existing record editing(existing records from Database showing in the grid not the currently added record).   'IsDelete' - This must be add 'IsDelete' but it should hide records showing in grid but it should not delete the records from grid dataSource.

Comment: I am new to Kendo. I am waiting for your reply. Thanks

Comment: I tried it's working fine. my another requirement is that OperationContext column should add dynamically and also want to hidden that column. I tried hidden true it's hiding from grid but it's showing in popup editor. Please help me to achieve this also.

Comment: I have one doubt . kendo datasource data id property is required or not. If id property is there then it's working fine otherwise isNew() method always returning true. 
Our dataSource data has  without id property(column) because we are assigning data dynamically. 
Please help me without id property or how to add id property dynamically for all rows.

Comment: Simple, for your case I would like to add 1 property to be added on your object collection which returned from server, usually I named it `local` `bool` type, from server it has `false` value and newly added object have `true`. Then change usage of `isNew()` with just check if model is local or not.

Comment: I need your help to solve this issue. please have a look this link,  http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9593069